# C++ Concurrency in action Thread Pool functioning

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I am reading the beautiful book "C++ Concurrency in Action" by Anthony Williams, first edition. In chapter 9.1.4 (the related source code is available at https://livebook.manning.com/book/c-plus-plus-concurrency-in-action/chapter-9/50) it is presented a thread pool which avoids the contention over a global queue of tasks to be executed, using queues local to each worker thread that belongs to the Pool. The related example code is the following:

```
class thread_pool
{
    thread_safe_queue<function_wrapper> pool_work_queue;

    typedef std::queue<function_wrapper> local_queue_type;
    static thread_local std::unique_ptr<local_queue_type>
        local_work_queue;

    void worker_thread()
    {
        local_work_queue.reset(new local_queue_type);

        while(!done)
        {
            run_pending_task();
        }
    }

public:
    template<typename FunctionType>
    std::future<std::result_of<FunctionType()>::type>
        submit(FunctionType f)
    {
        typedef std::result_of<FunctionType()>::type result_type;

        std::packaged_task<result_type()> task(f);
        std::future<result_type> res(task.get_future());
        if(local_work_queue)
        {
            local_work_queue->push(std::move(task));
        }
        else
        {
            pool_work_queue.push(std::move(task));
        }
        return res;
    }

    void run_pending_task()
    {
        function_wrapper task;
        if(local_work_queue && !local_work_queue->empty())
        {
            task=std::move(local_work_queue->front());
            local_work_queue->pop();
            task();
        }
        else if(pool_work_queue.try_pop(task))
        {
            task();
        }
        else
        {
            std::this_thread::yield();
        }
    }
    // rest as before
};
```

In particular, when thread_pool::submit function is invoked, if it is invoked on a worker thread it pushes the task on thread's local queue, otherwise the task is pushed on the global tasks queue. My question is:
This functioning does not make sense for me, how is it possible to invoke thread_pool::submit from a Worker thread? I imagine that all the submit API invocations will be done from "client" threads outside of the Pool managed by thread_pool class, so for them the thread_local variable related to the local queue will be always null, and then the task will be enqueued on global queue...for sure I am missing something since i don't understand how the proposed solution can work.
Thanks in advance for any help!!!

Comment: *"how is it possible to invoke `thread_pool::submit` from a Worker thread?"* A task running on the thread could queue another task. There's arbitrary code running inside `task()` call.

Comment: So, a submitted task() should in turn perform another submit()? I don't think this is the intended functioning, apart from performance issues (the task will anyway stored in global queue, before being moved to local queue), i don't think client is intended to know implementation details of the thread_pool class for using it

Comment: What do you mean, "moved to a local queue"? No part of the code shown will retrieve a task from a global queue and place it onto the local queue. The whole point of this optimization is that a `submit` call performed on a worker thread will **not** place the task on the global queue, but directly on the local queue. That's the only mechanism by which `local_work_queue` could ever become non-empty.